# Remove user from search list

Tags: 2007, people-search

I want to remove a user from user search list. How can this be done in SharePoint 2007?
I have already tried to user below settings, But I could able to add under contributor group afte few days!!1
GO to Central Administratopn >> User Profiles and Properties >> View User Profile
Under custom import, added additional user filter contition to block that AD active user.

(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!(mail=ITTest*)))

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Below steps well help you remove users from the search.

GO to Central Administratopn >> User Profiles and Properties >> View User Profile

Find out the username using search function and select delete.

NOTE: This will not delete the user from search result immediately. It will take some time (may be untill it re-index the Database).

Comment: Sathiya but next time when it gets crawl with AD,user will start to appear again in people result

Comment: I forgot to mention this. it will only work when you want to remove users who are inactive in the active directory.

Comment: Already tried above ideas, but still I could not able to add under contributor group. any other way to block? Thanks for helping to Satya & Amit Kotha

Comment: Are u trying to block a user who is active or inactive?

Answer (score 0):

- You can delete the user from the import source (AD, LDAP etc) and then recrawl. That will remove him (although thats more permenant).
- Depending on how good your XSLT is you can [edit the results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584121.aspx) and you should be able to throw in an statement that looks at the username and show everyone but that user.
- You can also remove the user programatically and recrawl, however, I'm pretty sure the user will show up again per the profile import schedule